# Why does my PS5 change the screen size sometimes?

Tags: ps5

Occasionally when I turn on my PS5 by pressing the controller PS button, the console will not use the full screen size of my TV.

- Sometimes it's the correct size, let's call that 100%
- Sometimes it's smaller than the screen, about 80%
- Other times it's overscaled, around 110%

I have tried to illustrated the difference with a picture as it happened this morning. I have highlighted the difference in pink.

[image: screen size differences]

Each time I experience this I have to go to Settings > Screen and adjust the display size.

Why does this happen and how can I ensure the PS5 detects the correct screen size? I am using a [Panasonic TX-39AS600B](https://www.panasonic.com/uk/support/discontinued-products/televisions/tx-39as600b.html) TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to confirm that this is an issue with my TV, and not my Playstation.

If the screen size is incorrect I can go into my televisions menu, and adjust a single screen setting, such as the colour balance, and the size will reset.

So I can only surmise that my TV is not detecting the size correctly from the PS5